# Paquetes de más al instalar con npm install

Tags: nodejs, npm

Instalé la versión de node 6.9.1 con la versión de npm 3.10.8.

Ahora cuando hago npm install en mi proyecto angular con grunt no solo me instala los paquetes que tengo en el package.json me añade un mogollón de carpetas más que no necesito para nada.

Además me he fijado que lo que me instala en el node_modules no es lo que solía instalar, la estructura de los package.json de las librerías que instalo son distintos.

Por ejemplo el package.json de grunt que me instala ahora es [**éste**](https://plnkr.co/edit/XuHXXOVSjHFcIaIxl8Ba?p=preview) y el que había antes era [**éste**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uVA9aiDq1IZQoynRGYIJ?p=preview).

¿Esto está bien? ¿Ha cambiado la forma de instalar paquetes desde node o es que lo estoy haciendo mal porque me falte algo?

He mirado en mi usuario pero no aparece el fichero .npmrc

Comment: Hola yo comienzo a notar algo tambien, al correr el comando npm i -s en el package.json ya no veo los paquetes como dependencias, me gustaria saber porque?

Comment: Hola @nelson.acos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, puedes crearla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) en lugar de ponerla como respuesta/comentario a otra pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más probable es que antes tuvieras npm 2.x y ahora estás trabajando con npm 3.x. Hay varias diferencias entre ambos.

Una de ellas es que el árbol de dependencias se ha vuelto horizontal, de manera que las dependencias de tus dependencias, que antes se instalaban en la carpeta node_modules de tu dependencia, instalando a su vez sus dependencias (y así, hasta varios niveles de profundidad) ahora se instalan horizontalmente quedando todo a la vista en el primer nivel de tu node_modules.

Si antes era

```
- node_modules
  - karma
    - node_modules
      - chokidar
        - node_modules
          - async-each
```

Ahora es

```
- node_modules
  - karma
  - chokidar
  - async-each
```

¿Cómo saber por qué se ha instalado cada paquete si tú sólo pediste `karma`? Bueno, justamente por eso npm 3.x también cambió la manera como se modifica el package.json de tus dependencias.

La dependencia es la misma, pero npm le hace cambios al package a la hora de instalar. Entre otras cosas, le agrega la carpeta actual donde está instalado (eso el package.json no tiene cómo saberlo) y la información de **quién lo ha requerido**, y qué versión ha requerido tal que la actual cumplió con esa condición.

Finalmente, hay casos de dependencias que antes se instalaban automáticamente y ahora tienes que instalar a mano (por ejemplo, instalar `karma-jasmine` ya no instala implícitamente `jasmine-core`), pero en general este inconveniente está claramente advertido en cada paquete.